# psSolid without linewidth or linecolor matching face

Tags: color, pstricks, 3d, pst-solides3d

Consider the following minimal example of a Mobius strip using [`pst-solides3d`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-solides3d):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-4.2,-1.7)(5.1,3)
  \psset{unit=1.5}
  \psset[pst-solides3d]{viewpoint=0 15 4, Decran=30, lightsrc=0 15 7}
  \defFunction{mobius}(u,v)
     {2 u v Cos mul add 2 v mul Cos mul}
     {2 u v Cos mul add 2 v mul Sin mul}
     {u v Sin mul}
  \psSolid[object=surfaceparametree,linewidth=1sp,linecolor=black!15,
     base=-0.5 0.5 0 pi,fillcolor=black!15,incolor=black!15,
     function=mobius,
     ngrid=8 72]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

The face colour changes depending on its orientation with respect to the `light` `s`ou`rc`e. However, the lines of each surface along the strip stays their original colour (`black!15` in this case). Is it possible to one of the following:

1. Remove the `\linewidth` such that the faces line up properly?

   Setting `linewidth=0pt` yields an image no different the above:

   [image]
2. Allow the `linecolor` to match that of `fillcolor` or `incolor` that changes with the angle/lighting?

Comment: I believe the `linewidth=0pt` lines may be an artefact of the PDF viewer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean something like this:

```
\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree,grid,
base=-0.5 0.5 0 pi,fillcolor=black!15,incolor=black!15,
function=mobius,
ngrid=8 72]
```

[image]

Comment: This is briefly mentioned in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-solides3d/doc/pst-solides3d-doc.pdf) (section **4.9. Definition of grating**, p 41): "The option `grid` suppresses the drawing of the gridlines."